# Carousel bootstrap is not showing properly plus description text is not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've just tried to implement the Carousel in bootstrap version 2.1.1 and am facing problem with the alignment as showing in the following link ( http://bonanza.mocorner.com/en/ ) the arrows are showing slightly out of sync with the image border.

am quite new to bootstrap in fact am bad with css in general :|... Any one can advise me on what I did wrong?

Update:

plus the description on the image footer disappear when you click next.. It flashes and goes away..

Answer (score 0):

I think if you make all images the same height, the problem will go away.

Comment: i just tried to make all the images the same size but that did not solve the problem

Comment: Not sure if I am seeing the updates: One image is 700 x 250, the other 700 x 300.

Comment: ops, sorry i did the change locally. I just removed all the images and uploaded new ones both 700 x 300

Comment: How about the widht:height ratio: Yours is about 2.33 while the one from Bootstrap is about 1.75.

Comment: but how can i change the bootstrap width:height ratio to match 2.33? another question, how did you calculate the ratio :)

Comment: To calculate the ratio, I divide width by height e.g., 700/300=2.33; you can try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591422/bootstrap-carousel-image-doesnt-align-properly; or you can adjust the width and height of your images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16879/discussion-between-mo-j-mughrabi-and-cam)