# Bootstrap - How can I use smaller pictures in my carosel but keep the over all size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see from [My website.](http://profile.duhuh.co.uk/)

the photos on the right of the page are not really well aligned. Now i know i could just make the thr correct shape in photoshop although when the browser is re arranged the photos would just get displaced and look bad.

**Question - How could I edit the carousal to possible just have pictures on the right and yet still have the text.**

Sorry if I'm not 100% clear, as it may not be possible what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Another possible form of question - is it possible to set a span within the carousel from which i can then put the picture?

Comment: Possible Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591422/bootstrap-carousel-image-doesnt-align-properly. Take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your carousel is not within a container.

Put `<div class="container"></div>` around the actual carousel container (`<div id="myCarousel"></div>` and it will align properly.