# Bootstrap Carousel Image Not Centered (Other Images Are) on iPhone SE Portrait Mode

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the site: http://sdgsdgsdgsdg.atwebpages.com/

Works as desired on Desktop browsers at any scale. Works on Mobile as well if in Landscape mode.

However, when using Portrait mode on my iPhone SE, the first carousel image is off center in Chrome.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

I've tried adding a style of `text-align:center` to only that particular image's div in the carousel and it didnt work.

Edit: As suggested that a previous answer should solve it, I used the code in the answer which was adding to my css: .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

and it still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Carousel image doesn't align properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591422/bootstrap-carousel-image-doesnt-align-properly). See @atrepp's answer.

Comment: @Alexander that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using this style right now

```
.unity-logo > img {
    width: auto;
    height: 386px;
    max-height: 386px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

just override above style in media queries ex.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:479px){
   .unity-logo > img {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
}
```

It should work..

[image]

Comment: also apply all media queries below your custom style properties so they can override the above styles.

Comment: i forgot to add the class selector in media query when i posted my answer, see the edited media query..

Comment: That works great. The image is a bit smaller than it was before, but I that's the only downside. I've accepted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: you can use height in px like you were using before but in that case the image will stretch.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```
@media(max-width:480px){
  .unity-logo > img{
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I understand the first code snippet. I just need to add parent to the container's class of the image. But the second snippet? Do I need to change media to something else? Because I don't want all my images to be 480px wide. Really not sure what it means.

Comment: no media queries are for giving different styles to elements deppending on the width of the screen. so `@media(max-width:480px)` means if the device width is below 480px then use these styles.

Comment: I tried adding your 2 snippets. Didn't work. Since I'm kind of new to this, I wasnt sure if parent needed a . before it such as .parent so I tried that as well. I also didnt know if i needed to add media to the img's class so I did that as well later. This is the css right now though: https://kianrafiee.github.io/unity/unity.css

Comment: by parent i meant the element that contains the img, in your case .unity-logo    ...   i changed my code , try the new one